# jquery array to php JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have various textnodes (p) and headers that I extract using jquery and store into an array :

```
var textnode = $(source).children("p:not(:has(img))").map(function () {
    return $(this).outerHTML();
}).get();
var headerone = $(source).children('h1').map(function () {
    return $(this).outerHTML();
}).get();
```

I need to take the textnode array and headerone array and pass it via ajax to a php script (which will consequently store it in mysql). Does serializeArray work in this case or could I use .stringify. Would I need to .decode this in php (version 5.3.4)?

Comment: is this javascript? and if it is, what library are you using?

Comment: @Praneet Sharma: Have you tried anything yet or are you just wondering?

Comment: i am not sure what you are doing. that does not look like proper jQuery at all...

Comment: I posted the slice of code that shows how I add elements into the array. @netcoder, I've been looking at jquery-json but I was wondering if decoding in php would also be necessary and how I would use the .ajax method to pass it to php

Comment: @Neal: yes it does, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Dereleased, when have you ever seen jQuery code that had just `.get()` at the end?...

Comment: @Neal: When you want to get a raw HTMLElement object out of a jQuery array.  This is not the same as jQuery's AJAX Get method.

Comment: @Neal: http://docs.jquery.com/Get#.get.28.29_-_DOM_manipulation

Comment: @Dereleased. the code above has **no** index. its just `get(null)`

Comment: @Neal: `function (a){return a==null?this.toArray():a<0?this.slice(a)[0]:this[a]}` is `jQuery.fn.get` -- Contrast to `jQuery.get` which is `function (a,b,d,f){if(c.isFunction(b)){f=f||d;d=b;b=null}return c.ajax({type:"GET",url:a,data:b,success:d,dataType:f})}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send it via jQuery Ajax, it will be automatically serialized and will be available to your PHP as a $_REQUEST array variable.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "store.php",
   data: textnode&headerone,
   success: function(){
     alert( "saved data" );
   }
 });

Comment: would that be enough or would I have to encode in json first?

Comment: well, you'll need for data to look more like: `'textnode=' + textnode + '&headerone=' + headerone` or `{textnode:textnode,headerone:headerone}`, but you don't have to serialize it as JSON.  If you send it like that, you'll access it using `$_POST['textnode']` and `$_POST['headerone']`

Comment: @Dereleased, according to the documentation jQuery .ajax will serialize a key->value array automagically.  So, you're correct that you can pass a string, but according to the documentation you can also send a properly formatted array and it will do the rest.

Comment: Nothing you just said isn't true =) I was responding to the suggestion of `data: textnode&headerone`

Comment: if you're going synchronous or don't care about a return value, .post is fine.  But if you're going asynchronous or want to get a result back, .ajax is your solution.  Don't shy away, it's really very easy to use.